# Ellipsis behavior (...) in method signature with an Iterable?

Tags: java

Say I have a method (in a library so I can't modify it) like so:

```
public void ellipsisArg(Object...objects){
    for(Object object : objects){
        doSomething(object);
    }
}
```

If I pass a Collection or an Iterable to this method, what will happen? Will the for() loop iterate over the collection, or will it accept the Collection as one object and pass the whole thing to doSomething()?

Comment: You can easily evaluate it by creating a simple unit test..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I tested it in Ideone (using Java6):](http://ideone.com/oXINiq)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*; 

class Main{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        testIterable(getStringList());     
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getStringList(){
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

        stringList.add("String one");
        stringList.add("String two");

        return stringList;       

    }

    public static void testIterable(Object...objects){
        for(Object object : objects){
            System.out.println("Object: "+ object.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output would be:

> Object: String one
>
> Object: String two

Unfortunately, the output was as follows:

> Object: [String one, String two]

So it took the whole ArrayList as one Object.

**EDIT:**

However, converting the ArrayList to a String[] produces the desired behavior, and is a simple task:

```
public static String[] convertToArray(ArrayList<String> stringList){
    String[] stringArray = new String[stringList.size()];
    // If we use toArray() without an argument, it will return Object[]
    return stringList.toArray(stringArray);
}
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/signyi)

Comment: Here you've got you answer :) `testIterable(Object...objects)` roughly   the same as `testIterable(Object[] objects)`. So to make it work as you expected you should convert your `List<String>` into `String[]` - `stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()])`

Comment: As you have figured out, there will be no automatic unboxing of the array. The vararg signature "Object ...objects" is the same as "Object[] objects" and if you pass one object in the array will be one item long, no matter if the object passed is an array, list or an Integer. Just call toArray().

Comment: It would be nice if this behavior was automatic, though I doubt it's a big enough issue to implement in the standard lib.

Comment: @Logician - Check my answer for some new info! See if that helps you figure out what's going on here!

Comment: I can think of a quite a few situations where it would be down-right bad to have it automatic and un-automate it is harder than to do it right from the start.

Comment: @Frederik I can figure, like wanting to pass multiple Collections to this method.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics is:

- if there is only one argument and its type is `Object[]` or subclass, it will be passed unchanged
- if all argument(s) types are `Object` or subclass, an array of `Object[]` will be created and passed.

Collection is not a subclass of `Object[]`, so it will be passed as a single member of newly created `Object[]`.

Also note, that this is resolved at compile time, so if you pass an `Object` variable with `Object[]` instance, it will be wrapped to another array. For example:

```
Object o = new Object[0];
ellipsisArg(o);
Object[] o2 = new Object[0];
ellipsisArg(o2);
```

The `ellipsisArg` method will get expected data for `o2` only.